# How to Format ListBox Column Width

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a ListBox with four columns, placed into the second row of my grid which also contains 4 columns. I use the Main grid's ColumnDefinitions to place four titles above the ListBox, and I need the ListBox that I have placed in row 1 of the Main Grid to have ColumnWidths that match according to the titles I've created.

```
<Grid Margin="12,0,12,6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="One" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Two" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Three" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Four" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>

                <ListBox x:Name="HistoryListBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding One}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Two}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Three}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Four}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </Grid>
```

All I see in my ListBox is jumbled data that is not separated into the proper column widths to match the TextBoxes above. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should define `ColumnDefinition Width="40"` to something like numbers

Comment: To have uniform size with above

Comment: The column width is variable because the screen size can change.

Comment: put it in percentages like Width="25*"

Comment: And set the `HorizontalAlignment="Stertch"` in the ListBox

Comment: Unforunately that doesn't work. I found a reference link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx describing the use of `*`.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what it appears in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is enough

```
<ListBox x:Name="HistoryListBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding One}"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Two}"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Three}"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Four}"/>
           </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, still couldn't get it. It just looks like a single row of text like `onetwothreefour` instead of being separated into the columns.

Comment: @Matthew check edit HorizontalAlignment="Stertch" on the Grid

Comment: I believe that did the trick! I'll have to play around with it to align the columns correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use  ListBox.ItemTemplate it means that you have a grid for each item of your listBox.

If you use the * on each column you get the available space equally divided to the columns but you still have a different grid for each element.

I would suggest using a Grid instead the ListBox or use the SharedSizeGroup properties if you insist with the Listbox.ItemTemplate approach and you will be able to have different sizes for each column and still maintain the 'illusion' of a grid.

Comment: Originally I would have preferred to use a grid, but I could not figure out how to scroll all of the items in the grid by row and have it auto generate more rows the more items that were added. My thinking was place a Grid in a Scrollviewer to get all of the items to scroll uniformly, but the modification of new row additions, and using this with population from IsolatedStorage and during the same app instance seemed overly complicated. Currently I am using the ObservableCollection which automatically updates the UI. If you could offer a code suggestion I would love to look at it and test it.